# Fonts not working when deploying on heroku, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'customfont';
  font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
 src: font-url('customfont/customfont.eot');
 src: font-url('customfont/customfont.eot?#iefix')    format('embedded-opentype'),
      font-url('customfont/customfont.woff') format('woff'),
      font-url('customfont/customfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      font-url('customfont/customfont.svg') format('svg');
 }
```

I have that in my scss stylesheet. The fonts are located in app/assets/fonts/customfont/

I tried what other posts suggested which is to put in various precompile methods in the application.rb but that didn't work.

I also tried to follow this guide
https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570
but didn't work when I hard coded the url either.

Chrome tools gives a 404 for the font. https://shelf-90690.herokuapp.com/fonts/customfont/customfont.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails/issues/10  this ossue should help

Answer (score 0):

Does it work as expected locally?

If yes and you have precompiled the code before pushing to heroku, try precompiling your assets on heroku and restarting the server.

```
 heroku run rake assets:precompile

 heroku restart -a your_app_name
```